# Passing value from one jsp to another jsp via a link

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

In my first jsp i am getting a list of nearby stores and their other attributes like name of the store, latitude, longitude etc. using Google API.

In my second jsp. i want the latitude and longitude of the particular store that the user has selected from the list shown in first jsp.

I am trying to pass the values of latitude and longitude via href but somehow i cannot.
below is my code:

```
side_bar_html += "<tr><td>" + place.geometry.location.toUrlValue(6) + "</td><td><a href='second.jsp?key='+place.geometry.location.toUrlValue(6)>" + "LINK" + "</a></td></tr>";
```

`place.geometry.location.toUrlValue(6)` gives proper latitude and longitude but while passing this value, nothing appears on second page.

Here's how i am retrieving the value in my second jsp:

```
<%=request.getParameter("key")%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html markup looks a little off to me. The closing apostrophe enclosing the href attribute is missing:

```
side_bar_html += "<tr><td>" + place.geometry.location.toUrlValue(6) + "</td><td><a href='second.jsp?key=" + place.geometry.location.toUrlValue(6) + "'>" + "LINK" + "</a></td></tr>";
```

You should check your generated source code and confirm that the href is valid. Also, try going directly to `second.jsp?key=test` to confirm that your jsp is reading the request param correctly.